# Damn small linux error

Tags: linux, dsl

I am getting this error while doing (Apps > tools > enable apt) to enable sudo apt.
Calling the dpkg restore script... Grabbing the compressed dpkg database and programs... Connection to www.ibiblio.org[152.2.210.81]:80 wget: server returned error 404: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Download error!
How to get out of this error ?

Answer (score 1):

change the DSL mirror ("Select Mirror" from the control panel).

There is a mirror list on the downloads page of damnsmalllinux.org

Comment: which one to install from current full mirror list ?

Comment: it depends on where you are located, I would ping some of the sites to check which suits best my location

Comment: I'm in Italy, I would try the Austria mirror or Belgium one

Comment: you said change the DSL mirror.  which one to select from control panel ?

Comment: I just found that it's another 404, I'm sorry but it seems really discontinued..
Try here http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/f/topic-3-9-16843-5.html